# Передать информацию о файле на другую страницу при клике

Tags: php, html, mysql, база-данных, get

Есть страница `PHP` с сеткой изображений которые хранятся в папке, а выводятся изображения на сайт при помощи `MySQL` запроса в базу данных, где хранятся пути к изображениям и информация о пользователе который загрузил.

При клике на изображение должна открываться страница с этим изображением. Так же на этой странице должна отображаться информация о том, какой пользователь его загрузил.

Вот тут вопрос. Как передавать эти данные при клике? Чтобы при клике открывалась страница с определенным адресом, вроде `id` изображения, например - `img.php?id=image123`. И как на другой странице отобразить изображение по которому я кликнул?

```
<?php
$img_url = "uploads/";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT image_name FROM images ORDER BY created DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo '
<div class="column is-one-quarter">
    <a href="img.php?id=' '">
        <figure class="image image is-square">
            <img style="object-fit: cover; cursor: pointer;" src="'.$img_url.$row['image_name'].'" />
        </figure>
    </a>
</div>
';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так а в чем проблема? Присваивайте картинкам в базе `id` и передавайте `$_GET`-параметром на нужную страницу, как вы и хотели - `/img.php?id=12345`

Код страницы `img.php` примерно такой:

```
$id = $_GET['id']; /* id вашей картинки переданный $_GET-параметром */
$connect = mysql_connect('mysql_server', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
mysql_select_db('имя_базы_данных');
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = '.$id);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); /* записываем полученные данные в ассоциативный массив $result */
$imageName = $result['image_name']; /* имя картинки */
$user = $result['поле_с_именем_пользователя']; /* имя пользователя */
```